# making threading concept with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, java-threads

I have a cronjob,

```
users
id      company_id 
1       1
2       1
...
10000   1 

cron_events

id event_name       company_id
1  birthday_party   1
```

So here i need to send email to all the users of the company 1,

i know how to do this by one by,

but i wanted to do this by multithreading concept, i am new to thread concept, anyone can guide me on this,

this is my existing code,

this is my Controller class

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 15000)
public void sendNotificationToUser() {
    Future<Boolean> sendNotificationToUser = cronService.sendNotificationToUser();
    if (sendNotificationToUser.isDone()) {
        logger.info(
                "-->Notification [Sent] to Patient ");
    }
}
```

this is my implementation class

```
@Async
@Transactional
public Future<Boolean> sendNotificationToUser() {
logger.info("-->in the function of sendNotificationToUser Function");

List<User> users = cronReferralRepository.findByCompanyIdAndActive(1L, true);

for (User user : users) {

Future<Boolean> futureCampaignCreated = processUser(user);
}

return new AsyncResult<Boolean>(true);
}

@Async
private Future<Boolean> processUser(User user) {

    System.out.println("Thread Name --> " +  Thread.currentThread().getName());

    Long userId = user.getId();

    String patientFirstName = null;
    String patientLastName = null;

    if (user != null) {
        patientFirstName = user.getFirstName();
        patientLastName = user.getLastName();
    }
    String patientFullName = patientFirstName + " " + patientLastName;

    //send mail code
...
}
```

Still my thread printing same thread name, how its possible, but i am expecting a different thread name,

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading essentially means running code on parallel threads.
Instead of having a sequential code execution you split this execution in multiple branches.

`Main thread        Main thread
 |                  |
 |                  |
 |                  |__ __ __
 | send mail M1     |  |  |  |
 | send mail M2 --> |  M1 |  M3
 | send mail M2     *     M2
 | send mail M3
 |
 |
 *`

By default your code exploit a single thread, but when an @Asynch method is called, the execution of this method is handled in a new thread.

What I think you want to achieve is to send mail in parallel threads, one for each user.
But, in your code, in order to exploit multiple threads you have to move the for loop before calling the @asynch method, so that every calls to this method will create a new thread.

Every thread created by the @Asynch is "destroyed" as soon as the @asynch methods completes.

Now the main thread can wait the end of all the called @asynch, or not based on your requirements.
Do you need to wait that all mails have been sent?
Or do you want to proceed in your main thread execution immediately after calling the @Asynch method?

**Case 1** waiting that all mails are sent.

`Main thread
 |
 |
 |__ __ __ 
 °  |  |  |
 °  M1 |  M3
 |     M2
 |
 |
 |
 *`

**Case 2** procede execution without waiting thread results.

`Main thread
 |
 |
 |__ __ __ 
 |  |  |  |
 |  M1 |  M3
 |     M2
 |
 *`

After you have answered those questions take further readings on Future and 
thread joins.

Remember that with spring boot you can easily configure the number of parallel threads, the queue size and other useful settings.

Comment: many Thanks, got some idea about the thread concept, and as you said i am reading Future and Thread joins

Comment: as you said i have edited some code, but still i am getting the same thread name

Comment: After adding the processUser in  a seperate class and calling it, worked for me. Also i have made

Comment: for (User user : users) {
    CompletableFuture<User> futuredone = (CompletableFuture<User>) testAsyncService.processUser(user);
    System.out.println("future done " + futuredone);
   } but how can i find, all the threads are completed

Comment: The new threads are generated in the @asynch method.
Consider that an asynch method will not work if it's called from a method in the same class or if it's a private method.
So you have to refactor a little bit your code.